# get image from asyncimageview

Tags: asynchronous, uiimage, imageview

I have a little problem, I use this class for load some image asincronusly

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AsyncImageView : UIView {
    NSURLConnection* connection; 
    NSMutableData* data; 
}
- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url;
- (UIImage*) image;
@end


#import "AsyncImageView.h"

@implementation AsyncImageView


- (void)dealloc {
    [connection cancel]; //in case the URL is still downloading
}

- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url {
     //in case we are downloading a 2nd image

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //notice how delegate set to self object

}

//the URL connection calls this repeatedly as data arrives
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {

    if (data==nil) { data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048]; } 

    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

//the URL connection calls this once all the data has downloaded
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

    //so self data now has the complete image 
    connection=nil;

    if ([[self subviews] count]>0) {
        //then this must be another image, the old one is still in subviews
        [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]; //so remove it (releases it also)
    }

    //make an image view for the image
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    [imageView setNeedsLayout];

        [self setNeedsLayout];
        data=nil;
}

- (UIImage*) image {
    UIImageView* iv = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    return [iv image];
}
@end
```

and this for load the image

```
AsyncImageView *asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 

asyncImage.tag = 999;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:indirizzoImmagine];       

[asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];
[self.view addSubView:asyncImage]
```

with this code all work but when I try to put asyncImage on [cell.imageview setImage:async.image]; the app crash, I think that I need to change the subclass in uiimageview but nothing...the same error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

How can I geto only the image?

Answer (score 0):

In AsyncImageView class synthesize imageCache using following code you can get the image

```
[imageView.imageCache imageForKey:str_ImgUrl];
```

Here imageView is the object of AsyncImageView.